# Improving write performance when we have a table with 5TB of data with 10 Regionservers

Tags: hbase, column-oriented

Lets say we have a table with 5TB of data with 10 Regionservers. we want to continue with puts to widely disbursed row ids in our table.In this case, increasing region servers will be helpful or decreasing to less region servers will be helpful? consider the region size is 256 MB.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for faster writes, go with random row-key(write load will be distributed).But not good for sequential reads.
You can start with 10 RS, then based on your write throughput, you may perform daily maintenance jobs that will do split-hot & compaction for your region.